# How to extract strings that appear more than once?

Tags: grep

I want to extract from a file all the strings starting with 'File:' and ending with '.png'. I'm running the command

```
grep -oE 'File.*\.png' list.txt
```

But this gives me a single long string starting from the first occurrence of 'File:' and ending with the last occurrence of '.png'. What should I do?

Comment: Hello, please consider to read this [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch from Extended Regular Expression (ERE) mode to Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) mode, allowing you to use the non-greedy modifier `?`:

```
grep -oP 'File.*?\.png' list.txt
```

See for example [Laziness Instead of Greediness](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)

Answer (score 0):

One long string starting with `File:` and ending with `.png` seems to be what you ask for.
When you want the have this split into strings without spaces, try something like

```
grep -oE 'File:[^s]*\.png' list.txt
```

When the strings have spaces, but only a dot before `png`, try

```
grep -oE 'File:[^.]*\.png' list.txt
```

When you don't want to use the Perl non-greedy grep, you might be helped with

```
sed 's/\.png/&\n/g' list.txt | grep -oE 'File:.*\.png'
```

When your input has double starttags like `File: and again File: before .png`, you first need to decide the output you like.